# Smart pointers in functions

Tags: c++, std, smart-pointers

This is strictly theoretical question.
When project is based on smart pointers, so practically all classes use them to wrap their pointer members, is it a bad practise to pass ordinary pointers to member/not member functions?
I mean, is it correct to have member functions like:

```
void Function(SomeClass* pSomeClass);
```

Or should it always be:

```
void Function(std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> pSomeClass);
```

I also wander if there are any important consequences (except standard const features) of passing const reference:

```
void Function(const std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>& pSomeClass)
```

What about situation when class is using `std::unique_ptr` to protect its members, and for example, pointer to its member is used in class private member function? Should it be wrapped too? Or should it be considered as design mistake?

Comment: Is the function doing anything with the shared pointer? Or is it just dereferencing it to use the stored object?

Comment: First of all, you should most of the time look at the new smart pointers in terms of *ownership* and not as a kind of self-deleting pointer. Then if you use smart pointers you need to use them *everywhere* for that pointer, just creating a `shared_ptr` for passing to a function makes no sense. Lastly, the smart pointers are supposed to be passed (or returned) *by value*, otherwise their semantics doesn't really work.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley; most of times, it is just dereferencing it to use the stored object.

Comment: Then there is no reason for it to take a shared pointer. That just arbitrarily restricts the usefulness of the function.

Comment: If you already have an object, it makes sense to pass it as a _typical_ function argument by reference or const reference. Thus your function always get predictable and safe to use arguments. As @JoachimPileborg mentioned above smart pointers are used to object ownership and _transfer_ of ownership.

Comment: Unless the function needs to know it's a *smart pointer* to affect its value then you should pass a *raw pointer*. So unless the function changes the *smart pointer* itself, it should accept a *raw pointer* or a *reference*. See this answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32873826/3807729

Comment: Interesting reading: http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the function only needs the pointed-to object and it must always be a valid object, not null, pass the **object by reference** (const or non-const, depending on the usual rules).

If the function only needs the pointed-to object, or optionally null, pass by **raw pointer** (to const or non-const, as per the usual rules).

If the function needs to share ownership of the pointed-to object, pass the **`shared_ptr` by value**.

If the function needs to modify the `shared_ptr` handle to the object (e.g. `reset`), pass the **`shared_ptr` by non-const reference**.

If the function needs to access information on the `shared_ptr` handle (such as `use_count`), but should not modify the `shared_ptr`, pass the **`shared_ptr` by const reference**.

Answer (score 5):

I think Herb Sutter has some good answers for that. There is a [GotW](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/) about smart pointer usage, and  [a more recent presentation](https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/02/cppcon-2014-back-to-the-basics-essentials-of-modern-c-style-herb-sutter) where he covers this. The new [C++ Core Guidelines](http://Take%20smart%20pointers%20as%20parameters%20only%20to%20explicitly%20express%20lifetime%20semantics) have a full section about smart pointer usage.

In a nutshell it all comes down ["Take smart pointers as parameters only to explicitly express lifetime semantics"](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines.html#Rr-summary-smartptrs). If you pass a smart pointer, this should imply that you talk/participate in ownership, either shared or unique. For non-owning parameters, raw pointers or (const) references are the current recommendation.